# Taskset -c command?

Tags: cpu

Could you tell me how to use command `taskset` on linux?

There is spec of my processor:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 16
Model name:            AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1900.000
CPU max MHz:           1900,0000
CPU min MHz:           1400,0000
BogoMIPS:              3792.85
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

When I put `taskset -c 0-3` in front of command for running openflow controller, I have worse result on cbench test than when I use command `taskset -c 0` in front of the same command (for running controller).

How is it possible? I expected that I have better result when I use 4 threads than when I use only one thread?

Comment: Is you command spawning 4 threads or processes? `taskset` by itself does not create threads or processes or does any other parallelization but only binds the threads/processes to a specific core or a set of cores.

Comment: I want to use all available cpu resources in first test ('taskset -c 0-3') and less resources in second ('taskset -c 0'). 
So, as I understand 'taskset' command, taskset -c 0 binds process with one core, and taskset -c 0-3 with all cores. Am I all right??

Comment: Yes, correct. But `taskset` does not create the processes.

Comment: Ok. There is a command for running openflow controller onos: 
`bin/buck run onos-local -- clean debug`
So, how to put taskset command?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated subject, depending on a number of variables, including which scheduler, CPU frequency driver and governor, idle state latencies, processor...
And while a lot of work has gone into making the various CPU frequency scaling drivers respond properly to work loads, there are simply scenarios where the results are surprisingly poor. This can occur with both multi threaded or single threaded applications. For example, ffmpeg and the odd way that it rotates through CPUs, is a particularly challenging application for CPU frequency scaling drivers. On my computer with 8 CPUs, I get better results with the phoronix ffmpeg test if I limit it to 4 CPUs instead of 8.
Let's work through a simple single threaded example. I have a simple CPU burn program that will do a little chunk of work, and when done a higher level script will spin out another processes do do another little chunk of work, and so on for some number of loops. If I run this job without restricting the number of allocated CPUs, then it takes 104 seconds, but if I restrict it to one CPU it takes 54 seconds. Why such a counter intuitive and drastic difference? Because during a chunk of work, the CPU frequency scaling driver / governor combination does realize the CPU is fully loaded and has begun to raise up the CPU frequency. However, meanwhile the work chunk ends and the next is launched. Now the scheduler doesn't actually know yet that the first chunk of work has ended, so it thinks that CPU is fully loaded and therefore decides to assign another CPU to the new chunk of work. The first CPU goes into a deep idle state and no longer influences the desired CPU operating frequency. Meanwhile the new CPU only begins to ramp up its operating frequency in response to the load. This cycle goes on and on with the result that the CPU operating frequency never does get very high.
Now, in the case where only one CPU is allocated to the job, there is never a load gap on that one CPU and ultimately it reaches the maximum operating frequency and the work chunks complete very much faster.

Example data (always the same job, no IO wait involved):

```
One CPU allocated:
(driver = intel_pstate; governor = powersave):
real    0m54.830s
user    0m48.112s
sys     0m0.272s

No restriction on CPU allocation (i.e. all 8 are available):
(driver = intel_pstate; governor = powersave):
real    1m54.938s
user    1m47.948s
sys     0m0.336s

No restriction on CPU allocation (i.e. all 8 are available):
(driver = intel_pstate; governor = performance):
real    0m52.851s
user    0m48.044s
sys     0m0.212s
```

So why not just use the performance governor all the time? Because, and in general, that would waste a lot of energy needlessly. It is just these special odd use cases where it might be better to just use the performance governor.